# Getting error: can't access Postgresql in ubuntu

Tags: database, postgresql

I can't access my postgresql datatabase because I forgot my password for PostgresSQL super user. What do I need to do?

I must enter pass when try to uninstall PostgresSQL or open psql database in terminal.

Comment: temporarily adjust the pg_hba.conf to accept other authentication method and then reset the superuer password

Answer (score 0):

First of all switch to PostgreSQL user by running this command on your terminal.

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

Now you have logged in as postgreSQL user. The next thing to do now is to access postgreSQL prompt. You can do this without using your password.Run this command;

```
psql
```

Now reset your password using this command. Write your new password in the placeholder 'new-password'.Don't remove quotes around the new password.

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

Now exit the postgreSQL prompt by using this command

```
\q
```

You have to exit from the postgreSQL user shell as well. Use this command;

```
exit
```

At last run this command to restart your postgreSQL service.

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Hope it works to solve your issue :)